# Using JSR-330 annotations with Jersey 2 + Spring

Tags: jersey-2.0, spring-jersey

I have been trying to use Spring 4 with Jersey 2 and notice that using the jersey-spring3 extension there is no way to make `@Named` annotated resources managed by Spring. They must be annotated with `@Component` to be managed by Spring.

If a resource is annotated with `@Named` HK2 seems to "take over" managing that resource.

**Resource**

```
import com.example.jersey.spring.Greeting;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.inject.Singleton;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Named
@Singleton
@Path("resource")
public class Resource {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Resource");

    public void init() {
        logger.info("Creating -> " + this + " injected with -> " + greeting);
    }

    @Inject
    private Greeting greeting;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getIt() {
        logger.info("Working on " + this + " Greeting " + greeting);
        return "Got it!";
    }
}
```

With the following Spring applicationContext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd" 
   default-init-method="init">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example.jersey.webapp"/>
    <bean id="greeting" class="com.example.jersey.spring.Greeting"/>
</beans>
```

Results in the following log messages being printed on start-up

```
Oct 18, 2017 3:11:44 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor <init>
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
Oct 18, 2017 3:11:44 PM com.example.jersey.webapp.Resource init
INFO: Creating -> com.example.jersey.webapp.Resource@6e199bab injected with -> com.example.jersey.spring.Greeting@533b3005
Oct 18, 2017 3:11:45 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 249 ms
```

And after a couple of GET calls.

```
Oct 18, 2017 3:11:56 PM com.example.jersey.webapp.Resource getIt
INFO: Working on com.example.jersey.webapp.Resource@40328bbc Greeting com.example.jersey.spring.Greeting@533b3005
Oct 18, 2017 3:12:03 PM com.example.jersey.webapp.Resource getIt
INFO: Working on com.example.jersey.webapp.Resource@40328bbc Greeting com.example.jersey.spring.Greeting@533b3005
```

So it appears Spring does create the bean but that is not the one thats used to service the requests. However if instead of `Named`, `Component` is used the entire lifecycle is managed by Spring.

Is there a way to use the standard `@Named` annotation and ensure Spring manages the lifecycle of resource completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is a way to disable HK2.

From latest [Jersey-2 Userguide](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/spring.html):

> the resources must themselves be managed by Spring, by annotating with @Component, @Service, @Controller or @Repository

Spring recommends the use of the more specific annotations `@Service`, `@Controller` and `@Repository`.

From the [Spring 4.3.12 Documentation §7.10.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-stereotype-annotations):

> **@Component and further stereotype annotations**
>
> The @Repository annotation is a marker for any class that fulfills the
>   role or stereotype of a repository (also known as Data Access Object
>   or DAO). Among the uses of this marker is the automatic translation of
>   exceptions as described in Section 20.2.2, “Exception translation”.
>
> Spring provides further stereotype annotations: @Component, @Service,
>   and @Controller. @Component is a generic stereotype for any
>   Spring-managed component. @Repository, @Service, and @Controller are
>   specializations of @Component for more specific use cases, for
>   example, in the persistence, service, and presentation layers,
>   respectively. Therefore, you can annotate your component classes with
>   @Component, but by annotating them with @Repository, @Service, or
>   @Controller instead, your classes are more properly suited for
>   processing by tools or associating with aspects. For example, these
>   stereotype annotations make ideal targets for pointcuts. It is also
>   possible that @Repository, @Service, and @Controller may carry
>   additional semantics in future releases of the Spring Framework. Thus,
>   if you are choosing between using @Component or @Service for your
>   service layer, @Service is clearly the better choice. Similarly, as
>   stated above, @Repository is already supported as a marker for
>   automatic exception translation in your persistence layer.